# The description of Snaphat seems to be incorrect

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

The description of Snaphat says:

> answer within 30 minutes of the question being asked, scoring 3 and
>   getting accepted

I got this hat for the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337853/azure-sql-server-fails-to-keep-data-consistency-using-a-check-constraint-and-a-t) that was asked on `2016-12-27 01:13:42Z`. I answered this question on `2016-12-27 05:59:16Z`, which is more than 30 minutes after it was asked. The hat was awarded the next day when the answer got third upvote.

It looks like a bug or incorrect description of the hat.

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288529/why-was-the-snaphat-not-awarded-or-why-was-it-awarded-incorrectly

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar, indeed, the same question. I did search for "snaphat", but I didn't realise that http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/ are different sites.

Comment: I'm looking to see what's going on here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The description of the hat is correct. The problem was the hat was still being awarded incorrectly. There was a bug that we missed in the query that has now been fixed.  Can you spot the bug in the line of code causing the problem?

```
And DateDiff(minute, a.CreationDate, q.CreationDate) <= 30
```

Basically, we had the answer creation date in the wrong position for the date comparison. Being in the wrong position, it always resulted in a negative number.  The negative value meant that the hat was being awarded outside of the 30 minutes that was supposed to be required. The bug has since been squashed and the hat should now be awarded properly.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the problem. It is unlikely that I'll be able to earn this hat again to verify that bug was fixed. In any case, you haven't revoked it and you can't earn the same hat twice...

Comment: Apart from the order of parameters, if I saw such line in my code, I would think that it is strange to calculate minutes of the date. I would call the fields `CreationDateTime` to make it clear that they hold not just the date. Actually, I would call them `CreationDateTimeUTC` or `CreationDateTimeLocal` depending on what timestamp they hold.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov it's calculating the number of minutes between a start and end date, which does store a datetime. The issue was with the start and end date being reversed. And no we didn't revoke the hats that were incorrectly awarded.

Comment: I understand that your field `CreationDate` stores both date and time. My point was that I'd call it `CreationDateTimeUTC`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I get that, I'm just saying that our naming convention is to use CreationDate for things.