# What's "the last day of hats" from a Philanthropist's perspective?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

The *Philantropist* hat can be earned *"on the last day of hats"*.

The [Hats page](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) states

> the hats get put back in their boxes on January 9th

So, when should I award the bounty?

- Is it on January 8th because hats end on January 9th at 00:00 UTC (so there will be no time to award a bounty on the 9th),
- or is it on January 9th because the hats will end at 23:59:59 UTC?

Comment: Place a bounty on both days and you'll find out :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah, ultimately, that's what I'll do :P

Comment: Make a bounty on this question to find out ;)

Comment: @John sadly, you can't bounty Meta questions.

Comment: You can earn it on the 9th, but you will instead be awarded the secret Schrödinger's Hat. Maybe.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only logical answer to this question is January 8th (UTC). If it would be January 9th, we'd never be able to see the hat. <s>Still, it wouldn't hurt if the developers had a second look at the code of the script awarding this hat. It wouldn't be the [first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288738/295232) [buggy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288538/295232) [hat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340848/4751173) of this year.</s> OK, works as designed:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Hats use UTC time for <strike>all</strike> most dates.  In this case, hats will end at UTC midnight on January 8th - the end of Sunday.

In order to get the hat, you'd have to award the bounty on Sunday January 8th, before the end of the day.

Comment: But days are also often padded to make sure that they work for all timezones. For example, I got the January 6th hat this afternoon (my time) which was hours ago and hours before the 6th on UTC. So I’d guess that there’s also a padding here, meaning you could probably reward it at the end of the 7th and it would still count.

Comment: @poke It's not really padding added to the date-based hats, it's that they start to be awarded when we hit the date in any timezone.  I haven't looked closely at the code, but I'd guess that would be about the same with this hat. When it's the 8th [in Baker Island](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/245123/5), it will mostly likely be awarded, even though we haven't hit it UTC. But hats end at midnight UTC on Sunday, so you have through then to get your last hat <insert tear>.

Comment: @bluefeet is UTC the standard timezone used for this kind of thing? I'm in UTC so fine by me :) But just curious as SO isn't in UTC, is it being used purely because it's central?

Comment: @MacroMan We use [UTC for most things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/what-time-zone-do-sos-servers-operate-in).

Comment: Cool - I'll have a nosy around meta SE more often - thanks for the link :)